# Separate when different rows in excel list appears

Tags: excel, ms-access, split, vba

I have a problem with an excel spreadsheet. I'm importing data from Access to a spreadsheet which I'm using as a picking list for my employees. It's sorted by transport numbers and I would like the spreadsheet to separate the rows when a different transport number appears in another colour.

Like this:

Transportnumber:

- 112233
- 112233
- 112233
- **223355[GREEN]**
- **223355[GREEN]**
- 555566
- 555566

Is there any possibilities doing this? The list contains about 10 more columns with data so it's important to make it easy for the employee to read when another different transport appears.

Comment: if you have Excel 2010, you can use Conditional formatting -> Color Scales on the Transport Number... Without using od VBA

Comment: Yes I'm using 2010. But it doesn't work to specify it on the transport number column. I want it to change colour when a new transport number appears and colouring all the following rows with same number till next trp nmbr comes.

Comment: I have about 2-15 rows with the same trp numbrs so I cant format colours on unique or dublicated values if I want to seperate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have agree to have only two colors, using VBA:

```
Dim Tmp As String
Dim Colo As Double

Tmp = ""
Colo = 14470546
For i = 2 To 9999
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Tmp Then
        If Colo = 14470546 Then
            Colo = 9737946
        Else
            Colo = 14470546
        End If
        Tmp = Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
'    Color the row
'    Range(i & ":" & i).Interior.Color = Colo
'    Color SOME columns.
    Range("A" & i & ":L" & i).Interior.Color = Colo
Next
```

If you are not sorted or you want different colors you need to use a array of colors... If you have blanks you need to add some other check... This it's only a starting point.
This code already start from A2. The columns you change in the last Range (now I write L)...

Comment: Seems good! Thanks. How would u write this if u want the code to trigger from A2 and down and coloring the rows with a width to L?